# Django Razorpay integration working on test server but fails during live session

Tags: django, razorpay

I am using razorpay integration with Django, I have tested the integration on localhost and it worked, also the checkout process and the payment collection works fine but when it comes to verifying the payment it seems to break on the live server.
The order amount and details sent to razorpay seem to be working fine but response capture is maybe breaking.
Below is my copy of views.py

```
class CheckOutW2(View):
    def get(self, request, customer_phone):
        dtt = dt.datetime.now()
        phone = request.session.get('customer')
        customer_object = Customer.objects.filter(phone=phone, date__hour= str(dtt.hour)) 
        customer_object = customer_object.reverse()[0]

        address = Addresses.objects.filter(customer=customer_object, date__hour= str(dtt.hour))
        address = address.reverse()[0] 
        
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        
        products = Product.get_products_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
        
        ot = 0  
        for p in products:
            summed = p.price * cart.get(str(p.id))
            ot = ot+summed
        ot_rz = ot *100

        context = {'userD':customer_object, 'address':address, 'ot':ot_rz } 
        return render(request, 'checkoutW2.html', context)

    def post(self, request, customer_phone):
        dtt = dt.datetime.now()
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        
        products = Product.get_products_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
        
        ot = 0  
        for p in products:
            summed = p.price * cart.get(str(p.id))
            ot = ot+summed

        order_amount = ot
        order_currency = 'INR'
        order_reciept = ('{}_{}_{}_{}'.format(dtt.day,dtt.month,dtt.year,customer_phone))
        # response =  client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, reciept=order_reciept )
        # order_id = response['id']
        order_status = 'created'
        if order_status == 'created':
            return render(request,'checkoutW2.html', {'rzp_oid':order_id})  


@csrf_exempt    
def payment_status(request ):
    response = request.POST
    phone = request.session.get('customer')
    cart = request.session.get('cart')        
    products = Product.get_products_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
    dtt = dt.datetime.now()
    
    customer_object = Customer.objects.filter(phone=phone, date__hour= str(dtt.hour)) 
    customer_object = customer_object.reverse()[0]

    address = Addresses.objects.filter(customer=customer_object, date__hour= str(dtt.hour))
    address = address.reverse()[0]


    params_dict = {
        'razorpay_payment_id': response['razorpay_payment_id'],
        'razorpay_order_id': response['razorpay_order_id'],
        'razorpay_signature': response['razorpay_signature'] 
    }

    try:
        status = client.utility.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
        for p in products:
            O = OrderItemss(customer=customer_object,
                            item=p,
                            quantity=cart.get(str(p.id)))
            O.save()    
        OR = Orderss(customer=customer_object,address=address)
        OR.save()
        orders = OrderItemss.objects.filter(customer=customer_object, date__hour= str(dtt.hour))
        for ordr in orders:
            O = Orderss.objects.filter(customer=customer_object)
            O = O[0]
            O.items.add(ordr)

        orders = OrderItemss.objects.filter(customer=customer_object, date__hour= str(dtt.hour))
        request.session.flush()
        request.session.modified = True
        order = Orderss.objects.get(customer=customer_object, date__hour= str(dtt.hour))
        context = {'userD':customer_object, 'address':address, 'order':orders, 'orders':order, 'status':'sucess'}
        return render(request, 'order_summary.html', context)
    except:
        context = {'userD':customer_object, 'address':address, 'status':'failed'}
        return render(request, 'order_summary.html', context)
```

Comment: got any errors?

Comment: can you share the error code.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, this was the problem with the deployed version, so i only got server error, couldn't recreate the error on test server